# How to scrape YouTube videos from channel?

Tags: video, web, youtube, screen-scraping

I don't have a lot of experience in programming (I know only some Python) and have no experience with the YouTube API at all, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. I am trying to get a list of YouTube videos from a channel, but I can't find a tool that would do this for me.

Is there any tool/script that could scrape the titles of YouTube videos from a specific channel and return them (preferably in an excel/csv file)?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel

Is this what you're looking for?