# Youtube api display limited videos from user's playlist android

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I tried to display all videos from my youtube channel using below json url. But it only 25 videos display from this url.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=Anklespankin&v=2&alt=jsonc

Actually user has uploaded more than 500 videos

https://www.youtube.com/user/Anklespankin

how to get all videos.give me json solution.

I have refer [Youtube Api to fetch all videos on a Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel) this link but in that there is solution

```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20"
```

but here i have to pass max result and if i write more than 50 i do not getting any result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with one call. You have to do it using more calls. First, you download the first 20 videos of the user, using:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=Anklespankin&v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=20
```

Then you check the totalItems property, to see how many videos he has in total. If more than 20, you fetch the others by offsetting **start-index**:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=Anklespankin&v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=21&max-results=20
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=Anklespankin&v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=41&max-results=20
```

And so on. Of course you can use bigger numbers like **max-results**=50, and then you don't have to make that much calls.

Comment: but i have more then 500 videos in my youtube channel so how is it posoible?

Comment: you have to do like 25 calls which fetch them in a sequence. You can't fetch all with 1 call.

Comment: Max limit of getting videos in one call is 50.

Comment: How to make a call for Second page?

Comment: The second link in my second code block answers your question.