# Getting a Youtube channel's video list as an rss feed

Tags: youtube, rss, youtube-api

How can I form requests using the youtube api to get the videos from a channel as an rss feed?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel), where a link to the new api (V3) is given, but I couldn't find it there. I tried with the deprecated syntax from api v2:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/UCqAEtEr0A0Eo2IVcuWBfB9g/uploads
```

but it only works sometimes.

I also tried:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

where I enter the channel id and the search key, but I get a 'bad request' error.

Comment: ans what about the api key ?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question in the headline:

Pre-append `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=` to the channel unique identifier.

For example, lets assume that the channel url is `https://www.youtube.com/channel/feed/UCpjNXONNE-JUz74ACsRCgcw`. So the rss feed URL would be `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCpjNXONNE-JUz74ACsRCgcw`.

Comment: It seems to still be working in 2021, thanks for the tip!