# 400 Bad Request while fetching videos of a particular youtube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to get list of videos of a particular YouTube channel.

I followed this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795628/5383573
Every time I am getting

> 400 Bad Request

Suppose I want to get all the video of NDTV Channel.

Its YouTube url is https://www.youtube.com/user/ndtv/videos

I went to this URL https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Fill the boxes as

```
Part: NDTV
Channel ID:ndtv
Max Result: 50
```

and click Execute

It gives me Request as

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=ndtv&channelId=ndtv&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And response

> 400 Bad Request

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.part",
    "reason": "unknownPart",
    "message": "ndtv",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "ndtv"
 }
}
```

How can I get all the videos in `JSON` response?
Sorry for my bad English.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) has five valid parts

> The list below contains the part names that you can include in the
>   parameter value and the quota cost for each part:
>  contentDetails: 2
>   id: 0 
> player: 0 
> snippet: 2 
> status: 2

A your error message states **ndtv** is not valid part.   NDTV  is also not a valid *channel id*. A channel id looks like this **UCtb0gXU-ht24V_fgeXGGjwA**

The easest way tof ind the channel id is to check YouTube

> https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtb0gXU-ht24V_fgeXGGjwA

Answer (score 0):

NDTV has 3 featured channels, those with channel_id

`UCZFMm1mMw0F81Z37aaEzTUA`,`UC9CYT9gSNLevX5ey2_6CK0Q`,`UCf9StUUEcbRpbvpdKx5eS_g`

The following GET requests will return json response.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId={ndtv_channel_id}
```

replace `ndtv_channel_id` with the channel id.