# get list of all videos for a certain channel with the new YouTube Data API (V3)?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I searched for this and could not find a direct way to get all videos of a specific channel 
what i found is to get channel's playlist then get playlist videos

is there any way to get all videos of a specific channel without getting list of channel playlists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Api to fetch all videos on a Channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel)

Answer (score -1):

Use the Search:list endpoint and enter the channelID to see the request

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Example:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCTWNIsdludLftzbP6AaQ4SQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. He asked for a way to have the videos of the Channel without having to go through the Playlists.

This will only return the videos listed directly under the channel and not the ones inside the playlists.

Comment: theCrius - he wanted videos of a specific channel, not the ones inside the playlists. read it again.