# YouTube API - Get all Video IDs from other YouTube Channels

Tags: java, json, youtube, youtube-api

Read this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel), but no correct answer yet. It is easy to extract video list from our own YouTube channel but my query is to extract full video list from other channels.

This URL results only 50 video requests.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50
```

I need to scrape all the videos from a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That request will return 50 video results, including a nextPageToken. Then you make same request, only passing in that pageToken to get the next 50 results, and so on.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageToken

Comment: Earlier I had used nextPageToken in the request. pageToken is the right parameter. Thanks!