# YouTube Analytics API: Finding total uploaded video count for a channel in PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm using YouTube Analytics API to allow users to connect with our application using their YouTube channel accounts. Now, after authorizing the user using OAuth2, I want to fetch the total number of videos uploaded by them on their account. However, I couldn't find any endpoint in YouTube Analytics API that could help me fetch that data. Is there a way to find the total uploaded videos for a channel using the Analytics API?

PS: I am aware of the public endpoint provided by YouTube Data API v3. However, I want to fetch that data for authorized users only.

Comment: you don't want to use Youtube API v3 ?

Comment: No, I want to use the YouTube Analytics API for my use case.

Comment: it's not the aim for this API, why are you limited to youtube analytics api ?

Comment: @mpgn I want to fetch the total video count of an authorized user.

Comment: you should re-think about how your app works

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it from the `YouTube Data API`, by using the [Channels:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#request). It also have a TRY IT! part where you can see the API request and response.

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M) here, that fully explained how to get the list of uploaded video in the Channel.

Also try to check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel) that I think it can help you a lot.

Comment: I already mentioned in my post that I am not looking to use YouTube Data API for my purpose. I am looking for a solution using `YouTube Analytics API` only in my use case.

Comment: I think it is not possible using YouTube Analytics API, that's why I recommended you to use Data API instead.  Try to check the document for [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#retrieving-a-report) for you to understand the use/limit of this API. :)