# Youtube playlistItems list API sometimes works, sometimes throws 404

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I have retrieved upload Id from a channel as shown here(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M&t=2s),
and using it as playlitstId here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it
Sometimes it gives 200, sometimes 404,

> Response {_body: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain":
>   "yo…003c/code\u003e parameter cannot be found."↵ }↵}↵", status: 404,
>   ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers…}

Additional info:
I have selected part as contentDetails,id,snippet
maxResults 50

Comment: I encounter the same behaviour. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You may check in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#playlistItems_youtube.playlistItems.list) the possible reasons why you got a 404 error in `PlaylistItems: list`. These methods could also return errors listed in the [Common errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#common) section.

- **notFound (404)**

  - *playlistNotFound*

    - The playlist identified with the request's playlistId parameter cannot be found.
- **notFound (404)**

  - *videoNotFound*

    - The video identified with the request's videoId parameter cannot be found.
- **required (400)**

  - *playlistIdRequired*

    - The subscribe request does not specify a value for the required playlistId property.

However, if it doesn't solve your issue and you think that it is a bug, you can file a report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=0).