# YouTube API: Not getting all videos of the given channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to get **all** videos of a given channel ID. But I am not getting all videos

code I tried to retrive all the videos of the channel:

```
api_key =  API_KEY
base_video_url  =  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
base_search_url  =  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?'
raw_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/' \
    'channels?key={}&forUsername={}&part=id'

def getChannelID(username):
    ''' returns the channel ID '''
    r=requests.get(raw_url.format(api_key,username))
    json=r.json()
    print(json['items'][0]['id'])
    return json['items'][0]['id']

def getchannelVideos():
   ''' returns list of all videos of a given channel '''
   chanId=getChannelID('tseries')
   first_url = base_search_url + \
          'order=date&part=snippet&channelId={}&maxResults=50&key={}'\
                        .format(chanId,api_key)

   video_links = []
   url = first_url
   while True:
      inp = requests.get(url)
      resp = inp.json()

      for i in resp['items']:
          if i['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video":
              video_links.append(base_video_url + i['id']['videoId'])

      try:
          next_page_token = resp['nextPageToken']
          url = first_url + '&pageToken={}'.format(next_page_token)
      except:
          break
      print('working') #used this to count repetitions of while loop
   return video_links
```

here the given channel is [T-Series](https://www.youtube.com/user/tseries) which has  11,537 videos so far 
[ [click to see the image of the channel showing the count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y1Qh.png) ] But I received 589 videos only

I used this line to count the no. of iterations while loop would do

```
  print('working')
```

for this I observed that the while loop ends after 19 iterations ( I have tried on many channels But same is repeating )

the is last (19th iteration)  Json data I was provided

```
{'etag': "cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/7SEM6nSU4tBD7ZsR5Abt5L-uqAE",
 'items': [],
 'kind': 'youtube#searchListResponse',
 'pageInfo': {'resultsPerPage': 50, 'totalResults': 15008},
 'prevPageToken': 'CLYHEAE',
 'regionCode': 'IN'}
```

why API not providing nextpageID though totalResults are 15008 ??

Comment: AFAIK the uploaded video count of a channel is retrieved via videoCount key value when listing statistics for a Channel object. Possible problem in your implementation: maxResults=50 in your GETs

Comment: @BoboDarph `maxResults=50` is an implemented limit on the API side

Answer (score 3):

Search call is not meant to be used to enumerate channels.

I was HTML scraping the channel > videos page until I found this recently.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/975887

Essentially the steps are

- find the channel ID of the channel you want.
- list playlists (`youtube.channels.list` set `id` to `channelId` and set part to `contentDetails`)
- find the ID of the playlist with name `uploads`
- list playlist items (`youtube.playlistItems.list` set `playlistId` and set `part` to `snippet` optionally set `maxResults` to 50)
- Page through results using `nextPageToken`

> If you only know a video ID, you can call `youtube.videos.list` with id set to video id and `part` set to `snippet` and extract the channel ID from the result.

This lists all videos uploaded by the channel, and unlike the search call, does not give up after a few 100 items, and results are always from the specified channel.

As an added bonus, this costs only 1-3 quota points per call (depending on what other `parts` you're requesting) compared to the search call which costs 100+ quota points for each call.

Answer (score 0):

As have been mentioned already in the comments, the max videos that can be retrieved from the result is 50. So if you wanted to access the other 51-100 and so forth, you'd have to use [nextPageToken](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters):

> **pageToken**
>
> The pageToken parameter identifies a specific page in the result set that should be returned. In an API response, the
> nextPageToken and prevPageToken properties identify other pages that
> could be retrieved.

Check this [Python on App Engine Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python_appengine) for sample in making Youtube API calls using Python.