# Fetch changed/new videos using YouTubeData API

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube Data API v3 to authorize a user with my app to fetch the video details from their channels and their subscribed channels and index those details to Elasticsearch.

I'm following this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36387404) to fetch all videos under a channel. Now, I met with a situation that I had to take only new videos in my next fetch. But, when I fetch again it also contains the videos that are already fetched earlier. I didn't find anything on this on YouTube Data API's documentation. I think this requires any token or any cursor field that handles the changes.

Looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the 'last fetch date' and then, use [/search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=es-419) to filter by date adding `publishedAfter` as a filter in your request. You hace a lot of filters in the search like the channelId, channel type, etc.