# Can I pull a list of all the videos a user posts via the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to pull a list of videos uploaded by a user using the YouTube API. I was looking at the [Channels List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) parameter it only seems to return basic channel information (description, viewcount, commentcount).

I then looked at the [Video List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) parameter and it only seems to return basic information on the video (publish date, title, description, tags, duration).

I want to find out what videos a user has uploaded via their channel name or channel id. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using Search videos and follow this request **`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20`**. I've tested and got the result that you've wanted. Here is the related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795628/5995040) to where I've got the code snippet. Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!