# YouTube API V3 find channel videos not in playlists

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can't find the answer to this one anywhere:

with the YouTube API V3, is it also possible to only list the videos from a **channel** that are **not** listed in playlists?

I am using this jsonUrl

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=....
```

hope someone has the answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, not from the API.

If you had specific playlists in mind, you could extract those videoIDs from the playlists and then check that list of IDs when fetching videoIDs from the channel. That's about all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all videos from you channel, go to [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and use the following parameters (choose list my videos):

```
type - video
q - LEAVE_THIS_BLANK
forMine - true
maxResults - 50
part - snippet
```

then Execute. It should return all vidoes. If there's more than 50, just use `nextPageToken`.

See related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795628/6577242).

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to get the videos that are NOT listed in playlists of that channel. Is that possible you think?

Comment: Maybe, if you tried using [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) get the videos, compare to the results of overall videos and find out which is not included in the playlist.

Comment: Thanks again! We are actually doing that, but I was looking for an easier way :)

Comment: This will also stop after 500 records (10 x 50).