# How list all videos from a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Using this API link, I get a list of videos from start but not all videos. I only get 300 to 500 videos.

Comment: An easier alternative: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwttM41xVBY

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit complicated. You have to make a few calls instead.

- find the channel ID of the channel you want.
- list playlists ([`youtube.channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) set `id` to `channelId` and set part to `contentDetails`)
- find the ID of the playlist with name `uploads`
- list playlist items ([`youtube.playlistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) set `playlistId` and set `part` to `snippet` optionally set `maxResults` to 50)
- Page through results using `nextPageToken`

Found this from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/975887

Hope this helps.