# How can I retrieve Youtube channel video list through the Youtube API in react-native

Tags: react-native, youtube-api

Is there any react-native plugin exist for retrieving youtube channel list? I didn't find one.
Or is there any way to archive this functionality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube API to fetch all videos on a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You must try `react-native-youtube`

and write playlist id or channel id in the props to get particular videos.

Comment: `react-native-youtube-api` package does not exist.

Comment: @harshit https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube try this