# YouTube API V3 publishedAfter / publishedBefore not working

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I need help on calling Services > YouTube Data API v3 > youtube.search.list. I tried several times a few days ago and it worked just fine. Today, it does not return correct year. It included 2016.

part   - snippet

channelid  - UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw

publishedAfter - 2018-12-17T16:05:58.000Z

publishedBefore - 2018-12-20T16:05:58.000Z

Answer (score 0):

Because [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) can only retrieve channels, videos and playlists according to `type` parameter, I assume that by specifying a `channelId` you are looking for videos and playlists during a given period of time of a given YouTube channel.

Playlists are easily retrievable with `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw&key=YOUR_API_KEY`.

And about videos because [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) isn't reliable I would recommend you to get all videos for the given YouTube channel and then proceed to your sort on your own. I would recommend you to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) to retrieve all YouTube videos of a given YouTube channel. The approach consists in getting the `uploads` auto-created playlist id of the YouTube channel by using [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with `contentDetails` in `part` and then use [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) to retrieve all public videos uploaded on this YouTube channel.