# How do I listen for new uploads from a specific channel in the YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api

I am making a Discord bot, and I want it to be able to use the YouTube API to fetch new uploads from a specific channel.

I have searched elsewhere, but they all say how to upload videos, not how to track uploads.

Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Edit: Tried PubSubHubbub but it was very confusing and I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here an example built on top of Node.js (v12) and [Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) and published with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/):

I wrote some comments explaining what it is happening:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

const xmlParser = require('fast-xml-parser')

const { URLSearchParams } = require('url')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

// add an xml parser
fastify.addContentTypeParser('application/atom+xml', { parseAs: 'string' }, function (req, xmlString, done) {
  try {
    const body = xmlParser.parse(xmlString, {
      attributeNamePrefix: '',
      ignoreAttributes: false
    })
    done(null, body)
  } catch (error) {
    done(error)
  }
})

// this endpoint needs for authentication
fastify.get('/', (request, reply) => {
  reply.send(request.query['hub.challenge'])
})

// this endpoint will get the updates
fastify.post('/', (request, reply) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 2))
  reply.code(204)
  reply.send('ok')
})

fastify.listen(8080)
  .then(() => {
    // after the server has started, subscribe to the hub

    // Parameter list: https://pubsubhubbub.github.io/PubSubHubbub/pubsubhubbub-core-0.4.html#rfc.section.5.1
    const params = new URLSearchParams()
    params.append('hub.callback', 'https://1f3dd0c63e78.ngrok.io') // you must have a public endpoint. get it with "ngrok http 8080"
    params.append('hub.mode', 'subscribe')
    params.append('hub.topic', 'https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCfWbGF64qBSVM2Wq9fwrfrg')
    params.append('hub.lease_seconds', '')
    params.append('hub.secret', '')
    params.append('hub.verify', 'sync')
    params.append('hub.verify_token', '')

    return fetch('https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe', {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: params,
      method: 'POST'
    })
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`The status must be 204. Received ${res.status}`)

    // shows the error if something went wrong
    if (res.status !== 204) {
      return res.text().then(txt => console.log(txt))
    }
  })
```

I used my channel id to do some testing, consider that the notification is not in real-time, the POSTs are triggered after several minutes usually.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for