# Get all videos of youtube channel using page token (android studio)

Tags: json, android-studio, try-catch, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch all videos of youtube channel.despite the most voted answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795628/7298663 I am unable to retreive all videos. the channel has 201 videos but my app is showing max 50.although I applied next page token. but unfortunately I cant program next page token call in my code. I have used JSON parsing and youtube data api v3. Can somebody help me in developing code to apply page token? below is the Json format for the videos retrieval.

```
 private void displayVideos ()
    {
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (jsonObject1.has("id")){
                            JSONObject jsonVideoId=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                            if (jsonVideoId.has("kind")){
                                if(jsonVideoId.getString("kind").equals("youtube#video")){
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectSnippet = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectDefault=jsonObjectSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                                    String video_id=jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                                    VideoDetails vd=new VideoDetails();

                                    vd.setVideoId(video_id);
                                    vd.setTitle(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("title"));
                                    vd.setDescription(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("description"));
                                    vd.setUrl(jsonObjectDefault.getString("url"));

                                    videoDetailsoArrayList.add(vd);
                                }
                                //  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and this is the url I am trying

```
    String url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCVMWWQ985A_-SESZUy_SsVQ&maxResults=50&pageToken=CAUQAA&key=[your API_KEY];
```

Comment: I am having same issue. I have tried using loop but couldnt find any solution