# YouTube Data API not returning the full data set

Tags: youtube-data-api

When the following request is made, it is not giving me the complete data set rather limiting to 10 pages and 500 records:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=50&part=id&type=video&channelId=UCgdHSFcXvkN6O3NXvif0-pA&pageToken=CPQDEAA`

It is only returning about 500 records out of 2126.

```
2021-04-05T11:18:13.330-04:00    3    [1|Q-Id]    [HTTP|Res: 20]
[HTTP Headers]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Mon, 05 Apr 2021 15:18:13 GMT
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2021-04-05T11:18:13.330-04:00    3    [1|Q-Id]    [HTTP|Res: 20] {
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "5snf-LkAO-ildQnoSYiawBtMrQI",
  "nextPageToken": "CKYEEAA",
  "prevPageToken": "CPQDEAE",
  "regionCode": "US",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 2126,
    "resultsPerPage": 4
  },
```

Getting the same behavior when I try the API here:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list`.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: there is the `nextPageToken`, use it to fetch additional pages, if you need more items

Comment: The pagination is set to 50, so a page will give me 50 videos and the nextPageToken after 10 iterations is being set to Blank. So I get only like 500 videos when I know we have a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you experienced is valid as per the following official specification of the request parameter `channelId` of the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint:

> [**`channelId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId)  (string)
>
> The `channelId` parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources created by the channel.
>
> **Note:** Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the `channelId` parameter and sets the [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter value to `video`, but it does not also set one of the [`forContentOwner`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forContentOwner), [`forDeveloper`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forDeveloper), or [`forMine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) filters.

Consequently, by paginating the result set of your API call

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=50&part=id&type=video&channelId=UCgdHSFcXvkN6O3NXvif0-pA`

you'll be getting no more than 500 video items.

Answer (score 0):

As said by [@stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar) search isn't the YouTube Data API v3 endpoint which meets your needs. Indeed you are trying to list videos from a given YouTube channel and by trying to do I would recommend you to follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660). The approach consists in getting the `uploads` auto-created playlist id of the YouTube channel by using [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with `contentDetails` in `part` and then use [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) to retrieve all public videos uploaded on this YouTube channel.