# I only (always) get 10 nextpagetokens for the Youtube Data Api v3; how can I increase this?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

No matter how many videos a youtube channel has, I only ever get 10 nextpagetokens, so with the '50 per page setting' I only get the data for about 500 Youtube videos, despite the response even stating the Youtube-channel has more videos ("pageInfo": {     "totalResults": 1418,) I want to get them all.

I have enough quota for the API in the google cloud platform to go beyond the 10 tokens. I have tried to find the setting to increase the nextpagetoken count, but have been unable to find it.

Does anyone know how to get more nextpagetokens?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) about the `channelId` filter:

> Note: Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the channelId parameter and sets the type parameter value to video, but it does not also set one of the forContentOwner, forDeveloper, or forMine filters.

I recommended instead using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) to list all videos of a given YouTube channel. The approach consists in getting the `uploads` auto-created playlist id of the YouTube channel by using [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with `contentDetails` in `part` and then use [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) to retrieve all public videos uploaded on this YouTube channel.