# How do I get channel IDs for all YouTube channels in Japan?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get channel IDs for all YouTube channels in Japan.

I tried to set the following parameters and call `/search` of YouTube Data API v3.

```
part: id
maxResults: 50
regionCode: jp
type: channel
```

`pageInfo.totalResults` in the API response is about 200,000 but actually I can only get 583 channel IDs.
583 is too little even if `pageInfo.totalResults` is an approximate value.

I would like to know how to get all the channel IDs in Japan, either by using the API or not.

I hope you will be able to provide the related information.

Comment: Other than using the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, there's no other way you could query the YouTube Data API for the info you need.

Comment: Keep in mind that not every channel has the "countryCode" or "localization" in its channel info, hence, the data might not be as expected. You have to rely in what YouTube provides and you have to stablish some criteria for filter the values as you require.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I implemented a very similar approach as below in [my YouTube captions search engine](https://codeberg.org/Benjamin_Loison/YouTube_captions_search_engine).

I tried to do almost the same for France. As said [@stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar) there isn't any appropriate endpoint to do so. However *with patience and work* we can make a kind of work around. **My method only retrieves Japanese YouTube channels having indirectly publicly interacted with your starting set (see below).**

1. Get a good starting set (in order to maximize the discover of the Japanese YouTube channels graph). I recommend you for instance to retrieve the [top 100 Japanese YouTube channels sorted by view count by using SocialBlade](https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/country/jp/mostviewed).
2. For each channel discovered by the comments retrieved at step 3 (automatically) choose whether or not it is a Japanese YouTube channel. You can retrieve this piece of information if it is available for the channel in the "About" tab. To do it in an automatic way check whether or not `snippet["country"] == "JP"` in https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY If `country` isn't defined you can try to guess (automatically) whether or not it is a Japanese YouTube channel by making more complex checks see [isFrench function](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-comments-graph/blob/9802fd2c5d11c6dd866f4e39343630b98a01b4e3/CPP/main.cpp#L1140). These checks are based on "About" tab and uploaded videos.
3. If the channel is interesting you (is Japanese) retrieve all comments (and so the YouTube channel about channel's videos and in the community tab using [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) with `part` containing `snippet` and `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId` filter. If this method doesn't return any data because a video has disabled comments then retrieve the videos list and comments associated using [(a)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) then [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) with filter `videoId`. The approach [(a)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) consists in getting the `uploads` auto-created playlist id of the YouTube channel by using [Channels: list](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-comments-graph/blob/9802fd2c5d11c6dd866f4e39343630b98a01b4e3/CPP/main.cpp#L1140) with `contentDetails` in `part` and then use [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) to retrieve all public videos uploaded on this YouTube channel. And if the YouTube channel contains more than 20 000 videos which is the upper limit for playlist size, use [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69121286/7123660) instead of [(a)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660). The script consists in faking requests done when browsing videos on a YouTube channel.
4. Then continue to dive into the Japanese YouTube channel graph by discovering Japanese YouTube channels through the comments found in your starting set and so on.

You can have a look for more details and some helping tools on [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-comments-graph) dedicated to the same approach for France (I was trying to list all comments let on French YouTube videos).

Of course you might need multithreading and group your YouTube Data API v3 request to reach `maxResults` upper limit in order to maximize your quota efficiency. Good luck.