# Is there any API to get list of YouTube channels over 100k subscribers

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube

I'm working on a tool that lists all the channel links having more than 100k subscribers. Is there any way to get a list of channels? Or is there any API I can use?

Comment: Start here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3

Comment: @OttoHanski YouTube API I can use to get the info about the channel. I want some way to get a list ot all YouTube channels, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Your question looks like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970958/how-do-i-get-channel-ids-for-all-youtube-channels-in-japan

Comment: In addition to @BenjaminLoison's comment, I also tried to get channels with certain amount of subs, but, you have to keep in mind that not every single channel has its location. Try to search for channels in certain region and add more filters to the search? What other criteria you have for search those channels? - keep in mind also that certain channels have their subscriber count private, so, probably those channels wont be included in your results.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [BenjaminLoison's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038078/is-there-any-api-to-get-list-of-youtube-channels-over-100k-subscribers#comment129005633_73038078), I also tried to get channels with certain amount of subs, but, you have to keep in mind that not every single channel has its location.

Using the YouTube Data API - [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint, you can try to search for channels in certain region and add more filters to the search.

What other criteria you have for search those channels? - keep in mind also that certain channels have their subscriber count private, so, probably those channels wont be included in your results.

See [this example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22JP%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22channel%22%5D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22nextPageToken%2Citems(snippet(channelId%2Ctitle%2CpublishedAt%2Cthumbnails(default(url))))%22%7D) for get channels from Japan<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> as mentioned, some channels does not have the "location" set in their info; also, YouTube returns videos and channels from other countries/locations/regions - independent of the region set in the request. So, you have to work with what YouTube provides publicly.