# Scrapping/ extracting Youtube Channel URLs

Tags: r, web-scraping, youtube, youtube-data-api, data-collection

I am trying to collect Data from YouTube and would like to ideally get the channel URL from as many Youtubers, who are active on one particular day and from a specific country.
The website channel crawler lets you collect big amounts of different youtube channels, however they only have a collection of 5 mio channels in total and are therefore not a complete representation. Most scraping tools I found let you scrape based on the URL but have no way of finding them in the first place.

Basically, before collecting more data, it is necessary to have the channel URLs of the videos to actually scrape the data.
Does anybody have any recommendations for websites or methods? Not to scrape actual channel informantion, but only collect as many channel URLs as possible?

Any advice is welcome!

Thank You

Comment: what about https://github.com/soodoku/tuber ?

Comment: Maybe [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) YouTube Data API v3 endpoint notably filtering with `publishedAfter`. IMO your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970958/how-do-i-get-channel-ids-for-all-youtube-channels-in-japan).