# For my channel, how do I return a list of all video ids with the youtube-analytics-api with private videos included (not the youtube-data-api)?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

**tldr**;

I need to return a video list using the `youtube-analytics-api` and not the `youtube-data-api`, **as private videos are excluded from a query to the public `youtube-data-api`**.

**/tldr**;

More detail:

I am interested in daily Youtube video revenue data per day for reporting for our YouTube brands.

1. I am currently using `python` with the `youtube-data-api` to return a list of all videos in a channel. I iterate through 50 videos per Channel per page until I have all videos and return a comma separated string called `video_list` like: `'videoid1,videoid2,videoid3'`.
2. Then, I plug `video_list` into a query to the `youtube-analytics-api`, so that I can get `estimatedRevenue` information per video per day. Revenue data is obviously not available through the `youtube-data-api` as it is private information, which is why I use the analytics-api.

**Here is the issue that I have though.** We have some videos that are currently private or may become private in the future, which excludes them from being able to be queried through the `youtube-data-api`. Is there a way to include a list of ALL videos (including private) through the `youtube-analytics-api`? I am able to successfully query these private videos using the analytics api. However, I don't know how to dynamically return a list of videos through the `youtube-analytics-api` as all solutions I have seen use the `youtube-data-api` for returning a list of all videos for a channel.

My workaround involves me *statically* and manually identifying the video_id for private videos, but this is a terrible way of doing this, since this python script runs daily. I'm hoping I can use the `youtube-analytics-api` to dynamically return a list of videos instead of the `youtube-data-api`.

This is how I'm currently getting the list of videos with the `youtube-data-api`, which is shown at around the 20-minute mark in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mSwcRb3KjQ) by **ClarityCoders**

```
def get_video_list(youtube, playlist_id):
    video_list = []
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            part="snippet,contentDetails", 
            playlistId=playlist_id, 
            maxResults=50
        )
    next_page = True

    while next_page:
        response = request.execute()
        data = response['items']

        for video in data:
            video_id = video['contentDetails']['videoId']
            if video_id not in video_list:
                video_list.append(video_id)
            
        if 'nextPageToken' in response.keys():
            next_page=True

            request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                part="snippet,contentDetails", 
                playlistId=playlist_id, 
                maxResults=50,
                pageToken=response['nextPageToken'])
        else:
            next_page=False
            print('video_list', len(video_list))
    return video_list
```

Comment: Using this method **with OAuth** I am able to also list my private and unlisted YouTube channel videos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660

Comment: @BenjaminLoison thank you this seems like a better solution. To summarize the answer you linked and answer my own question : 1) you could use the Youtube Data API *but with OAuth* and 2) also use a different query to get the video ids all at once rather than looping through 50 results per page, saving quota points.