# Get playlist ID from youtube video

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api, playlist

Is there any way to find playlist ID of youtube video using API, like through videoID? I looked into `/playlistItems` endpoint but I'm not sure where I can find the playlist item ID? I've tried to look this over everywhere but I'm at lost.

Answer (score 1):

I looked a bit, and the only method I can find would be limited to your own playlists and playlists on the video's channel (or other channels that you specify):

1. Get the video ID
2. If you want to check playlists on the same channel, get the channel ID from the video (see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource)
3. Get the playlists you want to check (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) - either your own playlists or playlists on
4. Loop through and get the items on each playlist (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list as you found)
5. Look for the playlist item that has the same video ID as the one you're examining (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource)

It's a bit ugly, and limited of course - maybe someone else will share a better method with us.

Comment: In step 4, instead of loop, you can use the approach I show in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71163891/12511801).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this workaround. I was looking for a straightforward way with minimum API calls but I believe it's not possible.  I think it's a pretty good solution cause it works perfectly in my case.  Also, the quota cost won't be so high.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be:

1. Since you have the `video_id`, get the *title of the video* as well.
2. With the title of the video, use the [search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint for search playlists that matches with the query/criteria - that is, the title of the video.
3. Loop the results from the search request and use the code I show in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71163891/12511801) for check if the `video_id` is on the playlist.

Example:

> *video_id*: **`eJjbnFZ6yA8`**
>
> *title*: `FULL MATCH - The Rock vs. Mankind – WWE Championship Match: Raw, Jan. 4, 1999`

Make search to get playlists that matches the search term: "`FULL MATCH - The Rock vs. Mankind – WWE Championship Match: Raw, Jan. 4, 1999`"

URL:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=50&q=FULL%20MATCH%20-%20The%20Rock%20vs.%20Mankind%20%E2%80%93%20WWE%20Championship%20Match%3A%20Raw%2C%20Jan.%204%2C%201999&type=playlist&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

[Try-it here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=es&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22q%22%3A%22FULL%20MATCH%20-%20The%20Rock%20vs.%20Mankind%20%E2%80%93%20WWE%20Championship%20Match%3A%20Raw%2C%20Jan.%204%2C%201999%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22playlist%22%5D%7D)

From the results of the search, get the playlist - for this example I took the first result I got from the search, then, I check if the video_id **`eJjbnFZ6yA8`** is on the playlist **`PLAamU2iv-fSuxZrVqQIBcrrZMTCMbBt2W`**

URL:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id%2Csnippet&playlistId=PLAamU2iv-fSuxZrVqQIBcrrZMTCMbBt2W&videoId=eJjbnFZ6yA8&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

[Try-it here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=es&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22PLAamU2iv-fSuxZrVqQIBcrrZMTCMbBt2W%22%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22eJjbnFZ6yA8%22%7D) for check the results.

Keep in mind that the `search:list` endpoint [consumes 100 quota points](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost?hl=en), so, the quota *might* be drain rather quickly - depending of the intensity of the search.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this workaround. I was looking for a straightforward way with minimum API calls but I believe it's not possible. I think it's a good solution, the only downside of this approach is the quota cost of search endpoint.