# How to retrieve Youtube playlistId using videoId and channelId using API

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying receiving `playlistId` using `videoId` and `channelId` with [youtube data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).  The problem is that `videoId` and `channelId` are the only values sent via Google PubSubHubbub Hub regarding video updates and I need to store only information related to predefined `playlistIds`.

`playlistId` is missing in [video list API response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), as well as I was not able to find a way to retrieve `playlistId` using [search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Is there any option to retrieve `playlistId` using `videoId` and `channelId`?

Help! Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, no, there isn't any constant time way to retrieve the `playlistId` using `videoId` and `channelId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

- Get all playlists of the given **`channel_id`** - [see the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?hl=en).
- Loop every retrieved playlist and check if the **`video_id`** is on the said playlist - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71163891/4092887).

Comment: That is actually a good option, not the perfect one but will definitely decrease the amount of quota usage, moreover, `playlistIds` are predefined, so that means I can search against them initially. Thanks!