# Python - How it is possible to scrap data from all videos in a Youtube Channel

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube

I need to collect data regarding all videos from a channel, or a group of channels, on YouTube. However, when I run the code below, it returns me only information regarding the first thirty videos of each channel.

```
# Packages
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

urls = [ 
    'pontodokaraoke'
]

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/{}/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid'.format(urls[0]))
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
titles = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "video-title")
for title in titles:
    print(title.get_attribute("aria-label"))

#OUTPUT

Karaokê Flor e o Beija-Flor - Henrique e Juliano Part.Marília Mendonça by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 17 seconds 12,552,764 views
Karaokê Eu Sei De Cor - Marília Mendonça by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 2 minutes, 58 seconds 12,446,045 views
Karaokê 50 Reais  - Naiara Azevedo Part. Maiara e Maraisa by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 14 seconds 9,338,854 views
Karaokê Dona Maria - Thiago Brava Part. Jorge by Ponto do Karaokê 4 years ago 2 minutes, 57 seconds 8,494,139 views
Karaokê De Quem É a Culpa? - Marília Mendonça by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 3 minutes, 25 seconds 8,215,633 views
Karaokê Largado Às Traças - Zé Neto e Cristiano by Ponto do Karaokê 4 years ago 3 minutes, 34 seconds 7,324,665 views
Karaokê A Mala é Falsa - Felipe Araújo Part. Henrique e Juliano by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 2 minutes, 59 seconds 7,169,674 views
Karaokê Apelido Carinhoso - Gusttavo Lima by Ponto do Karaokê 4 years ago 3 minutes, 19 seconds 6,370,830 views
Karaokê Que Sorte a Nossa - Matheus e Kauan by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 8 seconds 6,204,686 views
Karaokê Não Deixo Não - Mano Walter by Ponto do Karaokê 4 years ago 3 minutes, 21 seconds 6,102,888 views
Karaokê O Nosso Santo Bateu - Matheus e Kauan by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 2 minutes, 39 seconds 5,767,281 views
Karaokê Cobaia - Lauana Prado Part. Maiara e Maraisa by Ponto do Karaokê 3 years ago 3 minutes, 42 seconds 5,760,079 views
Karaokê Infiel - Marília Mendonça by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 18 seconds 5,755,782 views
Karaokê Notificação Preferida - Zé Neto e Cristiano by Ponto do Karaokê 3 years ago 3 minutes, 1 second 5,684,684 views
Karaokê Ainda Ontem Chorei De Saudade - João Mineiro e Marciano by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 9 seconds 5,123,973 views
Karaokê Seu Polícia - Zé Neto e Cristiano by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 2 minutes, 49 seconds 5,041,928 views
Karaokê Boate Azul - Bruno e Marrone by Ponto do Karaokê 7 years ago 3 minutes, 50 seconds 4,960,118 views
Karaokê Meu Violão e o Nosso Cachorro - Simone e Simaria by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 27 seconds 4,847,126 views
Karaokê Impressionando os Anjos - Gustavo Mioto by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 3 minutes, 32 seconds 4,751,701 views
Karaokê A Noite - Tiê by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 52 seconds 4,728,614 views
Karaokê Amor de Violeiro - Eduardo Costa by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 4 minutes, 26 seconds 4,514,054 views
Karaokê Ar Condicionado no 15 - Wesley Safadão by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 2 minutes, 51 seconds 4,074,179 views
Karaokê Péssimo Negócio - Dilsinho by Ponto do Karaokê 2 years ago 3 minutes, 12 seconds 4,057,122 views
Karaokê Supera - Marília Mendonça by Ponto do Karaokê 2 years ago 2 minutes, 24 seconds 4,046,549 views
Karaokê Pablo - Porque Homem não chora by Ponto do Karaokê 7 years ago 3 minutes, 31 seconds 3,913,661 views
Karaokê Regime Fechado - Simone e Simaria by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 3 minutes, 49 seconds 3,520,467 views
Karaokê Te Assumi Pro Brasil - Matheus e Kauan by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 2 minutes, 39 seconds 3,466,954 views
Karaokê Loka - Simone e Simaria Part. Anitta by Ponto do Karaokê 5 years ago 3 minutes, 36 seconds 3,413,632 views
Karaokê Na Hora de Amar (Spending My Time) - Gusttavo Lima by Ponto do Karaokê 4 years ago 3 minutes, 52 seconds 3,392,746 views
Karaokê Ciumeira - Marília Mendonça by Ponto do Karaokê 3 years ago 2 minutes, 59 seconds 3,309,492 views
```

Is there a way to collect data from all videos on a channel?

Comment: Important note: if you run the code until line 10 and scroll th web page until the end, the titles object will only get 500 values. However, the channel has 1153 videos

Comment: `I need to collect data regarding all videos from a channel` = what kind of information? be specific - see *[ask]*

Comment: Why not using [YouTube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) ?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Examples of desired data are shown in the output of the code in question: 
title, channel, tenuere and views.
'Karaokê Flor e o Beija-Flor - Henrique e Juliano Part.Marília Mendonça by Ponto do Karaokê 6 years ago 3 minutes, 17 seconds 12,552,764 views'

Comment: @BenjaminLoison as far as my knowloadge bout Youtube API go, it only allow us to get data from 30 videos per query :/

Comment: It is [maximum 50 results per query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#maxResults) and you can make [10,000 queries per day](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota). Isn't it enough ?

Comment: Not quite. Using Python I aim to able to extract data from 10/15 channels with 1000+ videos.

Comment: 15 * 1000 / 50 = 300 < 10000. Why "not quite" then ? @MateusSilvaAlvarenga

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I want to develop this and learn new things on python :)