# How to get the most recent video from a specified channel using the youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I have this code

```
url_params = {
    "part":"snippet",
    "channelId":CHANNEL_ID,
    "key":YOUR_API_KEY,
    "order":"date",
    "maxResults":1,
    "type":"video"
}
req = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?{urlencode(url_params)}"
data = requests.get(req).json()
```

But it uses 100 quota points and I was wondering if there was a cheaper way of doing it.

Comment: I like [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) which costs only 2 quota because the first video to come up from [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with the `uploads` playlist is the latest uploaded one.