# Youtube API search videos max count

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get all videos from Youtube channel using Youtube API.
I'm using **search.list** query:

```
request = youtube.search().list(
        part="id,snippet",
        channelId="UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q",
        maxResults=50,
        order="date",
        type="video"
    )
```

Then, I use **nextPageToken** from the response and get all results from the next page.
**But**, I can get max 500 videos and thats all, but the channel have 2293 videos.
How I can get all videos from the channel? For example, **video channel_id = 'UCnxmUrGMtpQT844Yd_l7Zyg'**

Comment: Search.list has a limit as to how many videos it will return.   Try using video.list instead.

Comment: @DaImTo [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) doesn't enable people to list videos from a YouTube channel, does it ? [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) consumes 2 quota and doesn't have the limit of 500 results.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison sure it does. Videos.list lists lists the videos for the channel the request was authenticated with.