# PHP Youtube API: Search videos where a URL is within the description

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a site where they have recently changed their domain. I'm trying to get a list of all the videos that contain that domain and change to the new domain using the Youtube API.

I am using the [developers PHP example on search list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#php), changing the 'q' value to be equal the old website domain and also adding a channelId parameter so that it'll only search inside their channel.

The problem is that some of the results do not contain the old URL in the description. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't any official YouTube Data API v3 endpoint to directly do what you are trying to.

If I were you I would [list the YouTube channel's videos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660) and then use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=snippet` to retrieve their descriptions and then I would locally filter the retrieved descriptions.