# How to use YouTube API with Videos:List and Channel ID?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to monitor my YouTube Live stream without using `Search:List`. How do I use YouTube API with `Videos:List` and **Channel-ID instead of Video-ID**? Use of `chart` filter in conjunction with videoCategoryId parameter seems a  potential solution but I fail to construct the URL correctly. I have tried the following urls. The problem with URL #1 is that I have to specify video ID which changes every time the stream restarts.

**Successful URLs #1**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[Video ID]&key=[API KEY]
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id=[Video ID]&key=[API KEY]
```

**This URL don't work #2**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=videoCategoryId=[Channel ID]&key=[API KEY]
```

Answer (score 0):

`chart=videoCategoryId=[Channel ID]` is incorrect, you should instead use `chart=mostPopular&videoCategoryId=VIDEO_CATEGORY_ID` `VIDEO_CATEGORY_ID` being one listed by [VideoCategories: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) as documented [`chart`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#chart) and [`videoCategoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#videoCategoryId). You are trying frantically to provide your channel id to a parameter (`videoCategoryId`) not accepting one.

Please don't make duplicated questions and update instead your [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73229757/7123660), as I commented it and it may solve the problem you raised here.

Comment: Please don't post almost same comment raising a question on several posts too...