# Youtube multiple live stream get first one

Tags: youtube

Following embed code can play if chanel playing live video it can play live video.

```
 https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCtOtzF5LuR0UIcKsKSG9_aw&autoplay=1
```

Problem is if that channel broadcasting multiple live how can get first live only?

examble channel

```
 https://www.youtube.com/c/IDHAYAMTV
 channel id: UCtOtzF5LuR0UIcKsKSG9_aw
```

that channel contain 15+ live stram but embed/live_stream picked only one ... how ? random? any filter?

Comment: What is your definition of *first* ? Is it the first one in the *Live now* list ? Is it the currently most being watched ? Is the first scheduled ? Is it the first that actually started ?

Comment: ok  currently most being watched or by date or being long time stream ...like that any condotion ... any command is there or not?

Comment: that channel contain 15 live stram but embed/live_stream picked only one ... how ? how filter?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73229757/7123660) and [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) may help you to answer both of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fund answer myu  self

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $json['items'] as $item) {
        $vid = $item['id']['videoId'];

    echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$vid.'?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
     if (++$i == 1) break;
    }
```