# I want to display all videoId via multiple channel id in youtube data API in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube-api

```
channel_id=['UCiT9RITQ9PW6BhXK0y2jaeg',
'UC7cs8q-gJRlGwj4A8OmCmXg',
'UC2UXDak6o7rBm23k3Vv5dww']

request = youtube.search().list(
        part='id',
        channelId="UCiT9RITQ9PW6BhXK0y2jaeg",
        type='video',
        order='date',
        maxResults=10
    )
```

I am able to see all videoId if i choose one channelId.In keyword parameter (channelId) take string not list so i did this

```
request = youtube.search().list(
        part='id',
        channelId=','.join(channel_ids),
        type='video',
        order='date',
        maxResults=10
    )

{'kind': 'youtube#searchListResponse', 'etag': 'O3-nwicpOKLtnp0e6OBdRVSWFTA', 'regionCode': 'IN', 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 0, 'resultsPerPage': 0}, 'items': []}
```

Can you please check what's the issue.

Comment: YouTube authorization is channel based. You only have access to the channel that was selected when the user authorized the app.

Comment: I have to fetch data from 10 different channel and that is not dynamic. I guess for ytdata API there is no need to authorization. The main issue is that i want to pass list into channelId

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Data API v3 [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint **can only filter for a single given YouTube channel id**.

> **channelId**
> **string**
> The **channelId** parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources created by the channel.

Source: [Search: list#channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) documentation.

So you are obliged to list video ids channel by channel and then regroup them.

Instead of using the 100 quota cost `Search: list` endpoint, you can use for a *1* quota cost [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) to retrieve the `uploads` playlist id and then pass it to [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), as described more precisely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244/7123660).