# YouTube sorting option for viewing oldest videos on the channel now missing

Tags: sorting, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api

Recently YouTube sorting option for viewing oldest videos on a channel gone missing [i.e.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrc6c.jpg) for I guess lots of people as I've heard on the internet. Is there's any workaround for this limitation like any extension or any uses of api or anything?

TBT I really don't understand why YouTube even try to remove such an useful feature. Now people need to probably spend hours scrolling to see a specific older video on a channel with let's say 20 thousands videos. Why not implement more of this useful feature to help users to find specific videos on a channel rather than deleting features. Maybe I guess nice job YouTube... ‍♂️ now you've got more dwell time lol...

Comment: AFAIK the only solution is to locally revert the most recent to oldest videos order [after having retrieved all videos from a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244).

Comment: @NorioYamamoto then you can [request a quota increase](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) or try [my no-key service](https://yt.lemnoslife.com).

Comment: Not a solution, but there is still a way to sort by Date added (oldest) on the android app YouTube Vanced.

Comment: 1/2 @BrunoSilva According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube_Vanced),  YouTube Vanced is discontinued since March 13, 2022.

Comment: 2/2 [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220315013242/https://github.com/YTVanced/VancedManager/releases/latest/download/manager.apk) is the latest WebArchive snapshot of the YouTube Vanced Manager APK datting from March 15, but once launched [the manager doesn't seem able to be able to download the actual YouTube Vanced app](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/81), do you know how to proceed nowadays to get a working YouTube Vanced app please?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison yes it is but you can still download the APK and side load it. There is a "non official" site where you can download the APKs I'm using it and untill now I did not find nothing anything malicious, but use it at your own risk! The site is youtubevanced(dot)com - again, I'm not endorsing this site, do your own research!

Comment: [@BrunoSilva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4157871/bruno-silva) To be safe I want to run an unofficial Vanced app in `anbox` in a VirtualBox but as described [here](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/81#issuecomment-1329340734), I am unable to make the youtubevanced.com app work in this environment. Do you know how to execute such an unofficial Vanced app in such a safe environment?