# ScrapeTube package for Youtube is not Working?

Tags: python, youtube, scrape

I tried to extract all youtube videoid from a channel. It was working fine till last week, suddenly its not working. In fact its not throwing any errors. Kindly help! Actually i tried to get the list of link. But Its showing empty link.

```
#scrape all the videos links
import scrapetube
link=[]
videos = scrapetube.get_channel("UCPXnayBvF7ynbG_I3VOTgIg")

for video in videos:
    str1="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+str(video['videoId'])
    link.append(str1)
```

**Input to access list:**

link[:]

**output obtained was:**

[]

Comment: Do you have any reason for not [using YouTube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244)?

Comment: Bcoz i am trying to see my favorite channels post and time, and their reach.

Comment: will you able to suggest some thing?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to [get the channel `uploads` playlist id and retrieve its content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872244).

Comment: Any package to retrieve it?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python).

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in a consent line in youtube that is fixed in version 2.3.1 of scrapetube. I suggest you uninstall any version <= 2.3.0 and install the latest one. That should do it.