# How to get the first video from any YouTube channel in new version?

Tags: youtube

In the previous YouTube version there was an option to get the first YouTube video as follows:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/MrBeast6000/videos?view=0&sort=da&flow=grid // MrBeast6000 channel Name

But the new version does not support this method. Is there any other way to get the first video of any YouTube channel?

Comment: By *first video* you mean the oldest one?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly not as far as I know, at least not nearly as easily as it once was.

The only solution is to [retrive ALL videos from a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel/27872244#27872244) and then **locally** revert the most recent to oldest videos.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Using [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) or [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) (a fork of the former, my current go-to)

You can use the following command-line expression to pull the first video:

```
yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/<CHANNEL-ID> --playlist-reverse --max-downloads 1
```

Haven't found a way to do that with the Youtube UI.