# API YouTube link in PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube-api

I could see that in the past, we could retrieve for example the most viewed Youtube videos using this link (http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed)
But I think that link no longer works.
So I don't know how to retrieve the most viewed, most liked Youtube videos, search for a video using keywords...

I tried to watch directly on "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos" but without any success

Comment: It's not possible with just querying the API unfortunately

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel

Comment: [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint will interest you as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this link which allows to retrieve the info of the videos thanks to a Youtube api key and one or more search keywords

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&order=relevance&q=KEYWORD&key=APIKEY

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).